# How to write an array into excel column?

Tags: c#

I used Excel.Range.Value but it writes the same value to all the columns' cells.

```
object[] weights = new object[10000];

Excel.Range startCell = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[2, cols+1];
Excel.Range endCell = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[rows, cols+1];
Excel.Range writeRange = worksheet.get_Range(startCell,endCell);
writeRange.Value = weights;
```

Comment: I used the Excel.Range and it worked , but all the columns'cells have the same value.
Note: array weights contains different values

Comment: You mean all your cells contain `weights[0]`

Comment: So it didn't really "work" and you have the same problem as the guy that asked the other question. Go check it out ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Range.Value property takes a 2D Object for non-scalar values.

Comment: That code is Visual Basic and we're on C# here.

Comment: I've removed the code example but the Range.Value data type still stands.

Comment: ... thus turning it into a comment at best.

Comment: Disagree. It's the right answer.

Comment: But a very vague and incomplete one, especially comparing to the one in the linked question :) I'll give you an upvote however.

Comment: + you too! I was wriggling slightly here as I don't know how to create a "2D Variant" in C#!

Comment: Bathsheba you are right :D It works